# NodeJS CPU usage is high even if v8 is idle

Tags: node.js, performance, profiling, cpu-usage, v8

I'm writing a small daemon in NodeJS designed to launch other applications, and I'm noticing that my CPU usage is sitting at 13% for this one process. This might not sound like much, but I have no idea why the usage is even at this level when, [according to profiling logs](https://gist.github.com/J-Cake/423c8fd10e82d3ae89cf1e0f318c0d5e), v8 is idling for 99.5% of the time. I'm wondering if there is anything that I can do so I can get a more comprehensive understanding of what NodeJS is actually doing and potentially what I need to do to reduce this activity. It would also be worth mentioning that the process's memory usage is normal using on average 9.2MB, only increasing at the beginning of the program.